# How to apply left join for blank or null value of first table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table as TABLE 1

```
BankId    |CompanyId|
23        | 2       |
24        | 2       |
31        | 2       |
NULL      | 2       |
83        | 1       |
          | 2       | 
          | 2       | 
29        | 7       |
```

I have a table as TABLE 2

```
   BankId      |CompanyId|AccountId|
        23        | 2       | 21
        24        | 4       | 22
        31        | 2       | 23
        45        | 2       | 24
        83        | 1       |
        12        | 2       | 20
        43        | 2       | 2
        29        | 7       |
```

Now here `bankid` and `company id` common among the two tables. Now I want to fetch all records from the first table based on company id and apply left join. But the problem is if i apply left join then it skips entry from the first table whose bankid is null.

Please tell me what should be the left join query ?

Sql query

```
select table1.*,table2.AccountId
from table1
LEFT JOIN table2
  ON table1.Bankld=table2.BankId
WHERE table1.CompanyId=table2.CompanyId 
  AND table1.CompanyId=2;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: No, a Left Join will not skip rows unless you got a WHERE-condition like  `table1.bankid >40` filtering the result of the join. Should be ANDed to ON instead.

Comment: It is skipping.

Comment: Show your current query.

Comment: Please show your query and the required result.

Comment: Btw, joining on CompanyID will result in a many-to-many join, are you sure you want that?

Comment: The row is skipped because you join on `BankId` (which means `table2` columns will be `null` for the row with a `null` `BankId`, and then you check (in the `WHERE`) if `table1.CompanyId=table2.CompanyId` which basically checks if `2 = null` for said row. Edit: here is a [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dir6pDQnw1venfqfsgtExh/0), the 2nd request shows the "raw" `LEFT JOIN` columns

Comment: Show desired output for provided source data.

Comment: In your `table1` some `BankId`s are `NULL`, some are empty. What datatype is it?

Answer (score 0):

`WHERE table1.CompanyId=table2.CompanyId` turns the result into an Inner Join, logically the ON is processed first and then the WHERE filter.

The rule of thumb is: *Conditions on the Outer Table are placed in WHERE, conditions on the Inner Table are placed in ON*:

```
select table1.*,table2.AccountId
from table1
LEFT JOIN table2
  ON table1.Bankld=table2.BankId
 AND table1.CompanyId=table2.CompanyId -- condition on Inner Table
WHERE table1.CompanyId=2;              -- condition on Outer Table
```

Answer (score 0):

is this your desired output for provided source data.

output

```
bankid|companyid|accountid|
------|---------|---------|
23    |2        |21       |
31    |2        |23       |
24    |2        |         |
NULL  |2        |         |
      |2        |         |
      |2        |         |
```

Query

```
select table1.*,table2.accountid 
from table1 LEFT JOIN table2 
ON table1.bankid =table2.bankid and table1.companyid =table2.companyid
WHERE  table1.companyid =2;
```

Answer (score -1):

join is broken when using
`table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.Bankld=table2.BankId`
Because use column NULL in Join

Comment: The join is not broken, because it's an Outer Join which returns a row even if the jon condition does not evaluate to TRUE